# Block add-in for Gmail Accounts in Outlook for Mac

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there any way not to support a Gmail account type in Outlook for Mac?

Since [Gmail accounts support has been announced](http://vhttps://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/12/14/announcing-add-in-support-for-gmail-accounts-in-mac-outlook/) I need to support also this account types. However, EWS requests does not work for Gmail. I would like to temporary block Gmail users installing my add-in, until I will adjust by backend, and switch to REST.

The only idea I have now is to detect `accountType` in JS and inform user that cannot use this add-in for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-in support for Gmail Accounts in Mac Outlook is not *currently* mandatory. If you do not wish to support Gmail *at this time*, you may mention this in the test notes of your submission.

Once you do this, your add-in will not be validated on Gmail accounts, nor marked as supporting Gmail Accounts in Mac Outlook.

Comment: It does not work... I included that in the test note, and I got "Note: We acknowledge your testing notes requesting us to not test your add-in in the Mac environment and to manually remove support for Mac.
However, please note, as per policy 4.12.1, your add-in must work in all Office applications specified in the Hosts element in your add-in manifest. For details, see Specify Office hosts and API requirements." They still ask me to support Outlook for Mac

Comment: @Frostless You cannot disclaim general support for Outlook for Mac; you may only disclaim  Gmail Accounts on Outlook for Mac.

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms, Is the Gmail Account type still supported? Is it going to be developed for windows clients? I've seen that announcements page has been deleted and I do not see any moves there.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail users would be able to install the add-in only if the add-in is successfully validated for the gmail account as part of add-in validation. Do you know if your add-in passed the Gmail validation? Are you able to see your add-in in the outlook Mac add-in store on a gmail account?

Comment: It is not released to the store yet. I'm developing it and sideloading. Some of my backend use EWS, which requires some time to change.