# Outlook web add-in does not support Outlook for Mac

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

When I submitted the add-in to Microsoft for review, I got this "Your add-in is not working when loaded in a Gmail account on Outlook for Mac. The minimum build number this supports is 16.9.1212." 
What does it mean and what can I do to make it support Mac?
I do think it is anything that I can easily fix by changing the manifest file.

My add-in' client side uses Office.js's `getCallbackTokenAsync` to get the token and pass it to the back end. The back end then use the token to access the mail item and send it to an external application.

I found this blog [Announcing add-in support for Gmail accounts in Mac Outlook](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/12/14/announcing-add-in-support-for-gmail-accounts-in-mac-outlook/) saying that "You cannot use Exchange Web Services (EWS) to access items in the Gmail mailbox". It is this the reason? So I need to use Outlook rest API instead to make the add-in work in Outlook for Mac?

Comment: Check also the answer for my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53174798/4828100

Comment: @Niko it does not work. They still ask me to support that.

Comment: in my submission response there was an info: "On subsequent submissions if there are no other failures then we will approve this add-in."

Answer (score 2):

Yes to make the add-in work on Gmail account, you would have to make use of REST API calls and not EWS. while using getcallBacktokenAsync(), pass isrest='true' to get the REST token. The add-in can detect if the account is a gmail account by using the accountType.

Comment: So if I keep using EWS API, I cannot pass the validation and get the add-in to the store?

Comment: Regarding getting the accountType.  Use this: `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.accountType`. It will contain a string `gmail` or `office365` etc.